# Как отключить CSS phantomjs

Tags: java, selenium, phantomjs

Пользуюсь Selenium, стоит phantomJS драйвер. Задача стоит в том, чтобы отключить css. Код уже есть, но как его отформатировать для джавы - не ясно мне.

```
jsDriver.executePhantomJS(
            "this.onResourceRequested = function(request, net) { " +
               "if ((/http:\/\/.+?\.css/gi).test(requestData['url']) || requestData['Content-Type'] == 'text/css') {" + 
                    "console.log('The url of the request is matching. Aborting: ' + requestData['url']);" +
                    "request.abort();" +
               "}" +
            "};");
```

Ругается на строчку с условием     `if ((/http:\/\/.+?\.css/gi).test(requestData['url']) || requestData['Content-Type'] == 'text/css') {`

Illegal escape character in string literal

Как поступить? Среда Intellij

UPD: так не работает:

```
(/http:\\/\\/.+?\\.css/gi)
```

Answer (score 1):

Потому что все эти экранирования не работают. Они применяются на самой строке с кодом и внутри оказывается не то, что надо. Собственно, на этом и появляется предупреждение, поскольку экранирование, предназначенное для регулярки на самом деле применяется в строке, где слеши и точки экранировать не требуется.

Ну и само собой, такой код не заработает. Чтобы исправить, надо экранировать ещё и сами обратные слеши.

Comment: Как именно? Не подскажете?

Comment: @jessez, ну \\ же...

Comment: Как экранировать символы, я знаю, но если написать так: 
`((/http:\\/\\/.+?\\.css/gi)` то будет ли оно работать?

Comment: @jessez 1. Да, если в коде ошибок нет. 2. А взять и проверить?

Comment: Проверил, не работает.